# Discord bot is active, but isn't responding to discord inputs. Testing using a simple "ping" embed command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot using a different syntax you could say and trying to integrate a bunch of different commands. The original command I was trying to add was the "fees.js" below. And the bot wasn't responding to the command, but isn't crashing in the console either. I tried testing with a simple ping command that would respond with "Pong!" within an embed, but still doesn't respond. Below I've attached my index.js, fees.js, and my test ping.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"] }, { partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION", "MANAGE_ROLES"] })
require("dotenv").config();

const prefix = "-";

const fs = require("fs");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands/").filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content === prefix + 'reactionrole') {
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('885603457938108476')) {
            return message.channel.send('You dont have access to this!');
        }

        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if (command === "ping") {
            client.commands.get("ping").execute(message, args, Discord, client);
        }
    }
});

client.login('Token');
```

fees.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'fee',
    description: 'This command will calculate the payouts for every major platform\n`!fee <amount>`\nexample: `!fee 100`',
    async execute(message) {
        const fees = {
            'StockX Level 1 (9.5%)': n => .095 * n,
            'StockX Level 2 (9%)': n => .09 * n,
            'StockX Level 3 (8.5%)': n => .085 * n,
            'StockX Level 4 (8%)': n => .08 * n,
            'Goat 90+ (9.5% + $5.00 + 2.9%)': n => 0.095 * n + 5 + (0.905 * n * 0.029),
            'Goat 70-89 (15% + $5.00 + 2.9%)': n => 0.15 * n + 5 + (0.85 * n * 0.029),
            'Goat 50-69 (20% + $5.00 + 2.9%)': n => 0.20 * n + 5 + (0.80 * n * 0.029),
            'Ebay (12.9% + $0.30': n => 0.129 * n + 0.3,
            'Paypal (2.9% + $0.30)': n => (0.029 * n) + 0.3,
            'Grailed (9% + 2.9%)': n => 0.089 * n + 0.911 * n * 0.029,
        }
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle("Fee Calculator")
        if (msg.content.split(" ").length == 2) {
            if (isNaN(message.content.split(" ")[1])) {
                embed.setDescription('Please input a number');
            }
            else {
                const [, number] = message.content.split(' ');
                Object.keys(fees).forEach(fee => {
                    embed.addField(`${fee} Payout`, `$${Number(number - fees[fee](number)).toFixed(2)}`);
                });
            }
        }
        else if (message.content.split(" ").length > 2) {
            embed.setDescription("This command takes only 1 argument");
        }
        else if (message.content.split(" ").length == 1) {
            embed.setDescription("Please put a price to calculate fees");
        }
        else {
            embed.setDescription("Please input a price")
        }
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

ping.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'This command will display the latency between Discord and our servers\n`!ping`\nexample: `!ping`',
    permission: 'USE_APPLICATION_COMMANDS',
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Ping")
            .setColor('#5104DB')
            .setDescription(`Pong!`)

            message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On September 1st, Discord made [message content](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ) a privileged intent. Maybe you should check your application settings over at [Discord Developers](https://discord.com/developers/applications)? Also you might want to consider switching to Slash Commands.

**EDIT**:

I noticed that you are checking if the command equals to "reactionrole", before checking for equality to "ping". Maybe try moving the if statement outside of that check?

Comment: I'd like to also add that even tho message content is a privileged intent, but if the bot joined less than 100 guilds - you still will be able to turn it on.

Comment: I will check these suggestions out, thank you so much!